# Is it possible to make reflections in (UP)BGE?

Tags: python, texturing, game-engine, logic-bricks

I'm working on a game and would like to know is it possible to make a reflective surface for stuff like mirror and high rise windows (via textures).

The image is from LEGO: Marvel Superheroes how to I add reflections like they did on the Empire State Building, but in blender?[image]

Comment: through textures no, that is done with an inverted projection that emulates the reflective effect of a mirror, I think that is what you want, if not, put an image with a visual example of what you are looking for to help you

Comment: Have you looked at the eevee upbge branch? Got bloom, reflections and all the fancy eevee stuff. https://blenderartists.org/t/does-anyone-have-the-upbge-eevee-branch/1159722/8

Answer (score 1):

**Information**

Both UPBGE 0.2x and 0.3x both have internal, real-time reflections.

You can get the exact same result in BGE but you'll need to use an external shader script.

**Blend File** (in a 0.2x release)

https://blend-exchange.com/b/XjnaWgkE

**Screenshot** (in 0.2x)

[image]